# Change the commit which a branch's name points to?

Tags: git

A branch's name points to the tip/end commit of the branch.

Is there a command that directly make a branch's name change to point to a different existing commit (e.g. some ancestor/descendant of the original tip commit)?

By "directly", I mean the command takes the commit to move to (or something similar to that) and the branch's name as arguments.

By "indirectly", I mean, for example, that committing, merging, rebasing, pushing, and pulling/fetching, move the name of a branch, but don't take the commit to move to  (or something similar to that) as an argument.

Comment: Do you mean that once the branch is merged(which would be the current branch you are on), you wish to move to the branch from where the current commit hash came from?

Comment: no. I mentioned "a branch", not necessarily a current branch. "merge" doesn't count, because it doesn't take the commit to move to  (or something similar to that) as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ git checkout the-branch
$ git reset <commit-hash>
```

If you also want to have your working directory reflect the state of that commit, add the `--hard` flag.

---

I'd be remiss if I didn't offer these 2 warnings:

1. You're rewriting history. Be careful with this if you've already pushed.
2. If you're using the `--hard` flag, you'll lose all progress done since that commit. Unless you have other references to your current branch's tip, you'll have no way (but `reflog`) to get back to the current state of affairs.

Comment: checkout doesn't move the name of the branch, but moves "HEAD". I am not familiar yet with reset, so I don't comment on it.

Comment: Thanks. can you explain why it does?

Comment: @Tim why it does what? It is exactly the command you are looking for. It moves the branch's reference to a different commit.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "If you also want to have your working directory reflect the state of that commit, add the --hard flag." Do you mean `git reset <commit-hash>` moves the name of the current branch to point to a different commit, but the working directory isn't updated according to the current branch? (2) Does `git reset <commit-hash>` make the change in the git repository or the staging area (and thus requires a following `git commit`)?

Comment: 1. Correct. By default, the working directory is not affected. 2. It makes the change in the repository. If you've used the `--hard` flag, you'll have a clean working directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch -f $BRANCH $COMMIT
```

Note that the branch you are trying to move can't be your current branch. See the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

> A branch's name points to the tip/end commit of the branch.

Correct (by definition, really).

> Is there a command that directly make a branch's name change to point to a different existing commit (e.g. some ancestor/descendant of the original tip commit)?

The low level command that creates or changes the target SHA-1 ID of a reference is `git update-ref`.  Using it is slightly tricky as it requires that you spell out the full reference name:

```
$ git update-ref refs/heads/foo newvalue [ oldvalue ]
```

(adding the `oldvalue` part makes it error out if the reference does not have the expected value; see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-ref.html) for details).  It is capable of breaking a symbolic reference as well.

The [`git branch` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) will allow you to move a branch to a new target commit, as [Corubba already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34557638/1256452).  It's more suitable for casual use (not as error-prone as `git update-ref`) but less so for scripting (where you want tight but complete control).

The [`git reset` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) allows you to move the branch to which `HEAD` is a symbolic reference, or to change the value stored in `HEAD` when `HEAD` is not a symbolic reference (i.e., when you're in "detached HEAD" mode).  It cannot move any *other* branch, though; and it also operates on the index (in anything other than `--soft` mode), which neither `git branch` nor `git update-ref` do.